# Help understand booking system

Tags: sql, entity-relationship

I'm creating a theatre booking system.

I am quite confused on how I can get multiple tickets to one booking, and able to query those tickets separately. (fields that are of no relevance to the question have not been included)

I have a ticket table:

```
ticketId, ticketName
```

Booking Table:

```
bookingId, bookingReference, ticketId
```

When connecting this I will receive the ability to create many tickets but the bookingId will change everytime, I will need the ability to find all the tickets associated with a booking and then query an individual ticket so it can be used for single ticket printing etc.

Can anyone help me understand what I need to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relationship between Tickets and Bookings is many to one. It would make more sense to have a field bookingid in the ticket Table rather than having a ticketId field in Booking table:

Ticket table:

ticketId, ticketName, bookingId

Booking Table:

bookingId, bookingReference

```
SELECT * FROM Ticket WHERE bookingid = foo
SELECT * FROM Ticket AS T INNER JOIN Booking AS B on T.bookingid = B.bookingid
```

etc

Comment: Indeed, the relation is backwards now.

Comment: But then when multiple bookings are created with the same booking reference there will be many bookingId's. This is then confusing.

Comment: OK, I kind of figured it out, I will be having all the tickets connected to one specific bookingId, I will test it out in my application and get back if there are any problems